# Default Value in Sun Editor in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to set a default value for the Sun Editor.

The default value i get it from database

I set the default value like this but it does not work.

```
<SunEditor
     autoFocus={true}
     onChange={handleEditorChange}
     setOptions={toolbarOptions}
     defaultValue={guide.description}
/>
```

The data in database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtP7J.png)

It only work liek this

```
<SunEditor
     autoFocus={true}
     onChange={handleEditorChange}
     setOptions={toolbarOptions}
     defaultValue={"<p>The editor's default value</p>"}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try api function from react-sun-editor

```
<SunEditor
     autoFocus={true}
     onChange={handleEditorChange}
     setOptions={toolbarOptions}
     setContents={guide.description}
/>
```

[link to Readme of Suneditor-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react)